# how to get JPQL query's result into java class

Tags: jakarta-ee

I've correctly running DOA

```
@Stateless
```

@LocalBean
public class WebServiceMethodDao extends BaseDao {

```
public WebServiceMethodDao() {
    super(WebServiceMethod.class);
}

public WsInfo getWebServiceByMethod(Long webMethodId) {
    System.out.println("getEntityManager() " + getEntityManager());
    WsInfo wsInfo = getEntityManager().
            createQuery("SELECT NEW mn.interactive.module.ws.dto.WsInfo( ws.wsdlUrl , ws.wsNamespace , ws.wsLocalPart , wsm.description) FROM WebService ws join ws.metaServiceMethods wsm  WHERE wsm.methodId = :methodId", WsInfo.class)
            .setParameter("methodId", webMethodId)
            .getSingleResult();
    return wsInfo;
}
```

}

Then I need to get "getWebServiceByMethod" query's result into java class.

```
public class WsFunction extends Function {



@EJB
private WebServiceMethodDao dao;


public WsFunction() {        
}


public WsInfo getWsInfo(String webMethodId) throws ServiceFault {
    WsInfo wsi = dao.getWebServiceByMethod(Long.valueOf(webMethodId));
    return wsi;
}
```

}

But in this case "dao" is null How to get JPQL query's result into java class

Comment: Sorry @WebMethod(operationName = "getWsInfo") is not here

Comment: Don't add code changes to the comment. Just edit your post.